# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was recently trying to create a hidden button called signupComplete, and suddenly now I get this error everytime I try to run the app. here is the error message I recieve in the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SignupViewController 0x10a3519f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key signupComplete.'
```

Im not sure why I am getting this. I even went back and removed anything that had to do with the signupComplete button, but I still keep receiving this error.

```
*** First throw call stack: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102846495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001025a599e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001028ca919 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x0000000102186530 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102842400 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
5   UIKit                               0x00000001013ad8a6 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1131
6   UIKit                               0x0000000101247b0c -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 245
7   UIKit                               0x0000000101248149 -[UIViewController loadView] + 112
8   UIKit                               0x00000001012483b7 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
9   UIKit                               0x0000000101248777 -[UIViewController view] + 29
10  UIKit                               0x000000010125f2c5 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 628
11  UIKit                               0x000000010126a6f5 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 401
12  UIKit                               0x000000010126b238 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
13  UIKit                               0x0000000101385895 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
14  UIKit                               0x00000001011b2993 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001004d5802 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001004ca369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001004ca1ea _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010043dfb8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010043f030 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
20  UIKit                               0x0000000101151024 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 10914
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001027d5d21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001027d55f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001027f146f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001027f0d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
25  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010459ef04 GSEventRunModal + 161
26  UIKit                               0x0000000101152e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
27  PickPiic                            0x0000000100002853 main + 115
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001031855fd start + 1
29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and relevant code.

Comment: Might be that your xib file is pointing to somewhere undefined. Did you edit the IBOutlet/IBActions without updating the connection from the xib?

Comment: Yeah looks like a NIB binding problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when running app in simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804270/error-when-running-app-in-simulator)

Comment: The problems seems to be in your XIB, delete that button and try. I had same issue where I had a button I was not using in XIB ( I deleted the Action methods but still I was getting this exception).

Comment: can you upVote comments :P if yes, please do :)